# Unzipping the file on device

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, unzip

Following command worked fine on Simulator. But this command does not work on Devices.

```
#define kUnZipCommand @"unzip \"%@\" -d\"%@\""
NSString *anUnZipCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:kUnZipCommand, aFileName, aDirectoryPath];       
system([anUnZipCommand UTF8String]);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `system()` call is unsupported on the device because of sandboxing. You need to link with a [library](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home) to handle Zip files.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a framework such as [ZipKit](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home).

Answer (score 2):

I've used [`NuZip`](https://github.com/timburks/nuzip) in the past. You call it in the same way you would call unzip on the command line:

```
[NuZip unzip:@"MyArchive.zip -d my_directory"];
```